# async process dialog not showing in application in android

Tags: android

async process dialog is not showing in application in android. Can anybody tell me what the problem is?

My code

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
  new FetchTask(getBaseContext()).execute(null); 
}

 public class FetchTask extends AsyncTask<Object, ArrayList,ArrayList> 
 { 

     private ProgressDialog dlg; 
     private Context ctx; 

     public FetchTask(Context context) { 
         ctx = context; 
     } 

     @Override 
     protected void onPreExecute() { 
         dlg = new ProgressDialog(ctx); 
         dlg.setMessage("Loading...."); 
         dlg.show();
         super.onPreExecute(); 
     } 

     @Override 
     protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList parserValue) { 
         dlg.dismiss(); 

           for(int i=0;i<parservalue.size();i++)
             {
                DomParserDataSet dataset=(DomParserDataSet)parservalue.get(i);  
                 if(dataset.getToken_string().length()>1)
                      {


                  Intent homeIntent=new Intent(ctx,HelloTabWidget.class);
                  homeIntent.putExtra("strUserName", username);
                  homeIntent.putExtra("strPassword",password );
                  homeIntent.putExtra("questGroupId",dataset.getQuest_group_id());
                  homeIntent.putExtra("userid",dataset.getUser_id());
                  homeIntent.putExtra("systemuserid", dataset.getSystem_user_id());
                  homeIntent.putExtra("providerid",dataset.getIndex_provider_id());
                       startActivity(homeIntent);
                   //startActivity(new Intent(this,HelloTabWidget.class));

                   }
                   else
                   {            

                     DomParserDataSet dataset1=(DomParserDataSet)parservalue.get(i);   
                     AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
                      alertbox.setMessage(dataset1.getError_value());
                         alertbox.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                               // the button was clicked

                            dialog.cancel();

                           }
                       });

                       // show it
                       alertbox.show();       
                   }

             } 

             // display data 
         }

  @Override
  protected ArrayList doInBackground(Object... arg0) {       

   try
      {
          username=edtUserName.getText().toString();
          password=edtPassword.getText().toString();
          WebService service=new WebService();
          String webservicevalue=service.callServer(SOAP_ACTION,"", username,password,URL);
            webservicevalue=decodeXMLData(webservicevalue);
            DomParser xmlParser=new DomParser();
           parservalue=xmlParser.parseXmlFile(webservicevalue);

           String parservalue1=Integer.toString(parservalue.size());

           Log.d("parser value size is",parservalue1);


            }
             catch (Exception e) {
       // TODO: handle exception
              e.printStackTrace();
      }          

             return parservalue;
       } 

 }
```

Can anybody tell me what I have to change?

Comment: Just to rule out that it might be something else: have you tried to remove all code other than what is related to the `ProgressDialog`. Run your app and see if it still doesn't display (just put a 500 millisecond sleep or something inside `doInBackground` so that you simulate some processing time).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Arhimed, this isn't correct. Leaving the answer for future references though.

<strike>I think you need to move `super.onPreExecute();` to the first line in `onPreExecute()`, like this:</strike>

```
 @Override 
 protected void onPreExecute() { 
     super.onPreExecute();
     dlg = new ProgressDialog(ctx); 
     dlg.setMessage("Loading...."); 
     dlg.show(); 
 }
```

Comment: This can not be a solution, because `AsyncTask.onPreExecute()` method has empty body (no code is placed inside of it). So you can even remove `super.onPreExecute()` - nothing will change.

Comment: @Arhimed: I didn't know the details about `onPreExecute`, I just made a qualified guess knowing that it is generally best to call the super method first thing in an overridden method (at least in setup/pre-methods). Not sure I think my answer is so bad it deserves a down-vote though...

Comment: @Nailuj - you are right - probably I should not have down voted, since you've just made a suggestion ("I think .."). Please, update your answer - then I'll be able to remove my downvote.

Comment: @Arhimed: I've updated the answer as requested. Thanks for the follow-up :)

Comment: @Arhimed: just in case you missed it, you don't have to add an up-vote to remove a down-vote, you can simply re-click the down-vote and it will go away (unless the up-vote isn't from you and somebody else found this answer worth up-voting, if so I'd like to know why ;p)

Comment: @Nailuj: Probably, but not sure if the up vote is a result of me. However let's come back to the asker's request, since looks like we don't serve the initial goal of being here - the asker is still not given an idea of how to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, in addition to Nailuj's guess here is another couple of **qualified guesses**:

1. Could it be `ProgressDialog` constructor expects an instance of a wrapping `Activity` as a context instead of `Activity.getBaseContext()` (BTW, I hope the getBaseContext() is called on an `Activity` instance (?))?
2. Could it be `FetchTask.doInBackground()` runs so quickly (maybe some error happens, see what LogCat says) that `ProgressDialog` just have no time to show up?

Comment: I written code for one activity to another display progress bar